# Naive Bayes classifier for OKCupid profiles

Tags: python

I tried to write a naive Bayes classifier to classify OkCupid profiles, and I was wondering if you could give me feedback on my code.  The classifier performs no better than chance and the coding style is probably not great either.  I had a training set of 20 good profiles and 20 bad profiles, and a test set of 16 good and 29 bad, so I don't know if I am classifying poorly or if I just don't have enough data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Naive Bayes classifier for OkCupid data.  The features are the words in
# the profile and the classes are HIGH and LOW.  This is used to
# predict the rating I would give a profile.

# TODO: tweak the classifier so it works better.

from subprocess import call
from math import sqrt

# File containing training data in the form "<rating> <username>"
TRAINING_DATA = "train.dta"

# File containing test set in the form "<rating> <username>"
TEST_DATA = "test.dta"

# Dictionary
dictionary = "TWL06.txt"

# Hash table containing words in highly-ranked profiles.
HIGH_WORDS = {}

# Hash table containing words in low-ranked profiles.
LOW_WORDS = {}

# Number of users in each category
hi = 0
low = 0

# Add training data to the hash tables.
t = open(TRAINING_DATA, 'r')
for user in t:
    rating = int(user.split(" ")[0])
    name = user.split(" ")[1]

    # Count users
    if rating == 1:
        hi += 1
    else:
        low += 1

    # Get data for each user
    call(["curl", "-o", "tmp.dta", "http://www.okcupid.com/profile/" + name])
    d = open("tmp.dta", 'r')

    # Get word list from user
    words = {}
    for line in d:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if "/" in word or "=" in word or "<" in word or ">" in word or "()" in word or "&" in word or len(word) > 10:
                continue
            words[word.rstrip().lower()] = None
    d.close()

    # Add words in this word list to our master word lists
    for word in words:
        if rating == 1:
            if word in HIGH_WORDS:
                HIGH_WORDS[word] += 1
            else:
                HIGH_WORDS[word] = 1
        else:
            if word in LOW_WORDS:
                LOW_WORDS[word] += 1
            else:
                LOW_WORDS[word] = 1
t.close()

print HIGH_WORDS
print LOW_WORDS

# Classify a point, assuming training has already happened.
# P(C | F1 ... Fn) proportionate to P(C) * P(F1 | C) * ... * P(Fn | C)
def classify(username):
    # P(C)
    Phi = float(hi) / float(hi + low)
    Plow = float(low) / float(hi + low)
    ratio = Phi / Plow
    # Get data
    call(["curl", "-o", "tmp.dta", "http://www.okcupid.com/profile/" + username])
    d = open("tmp.dta", 'r')
    for line in d:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            # Calculate the probability of the feature given a class
            if word in HIGH_WORDS:
                numHi = float(HIGH_WORDS[word])
            else:
                numHi = 1
            if word in LOW_WORDS:
                numLow = float(LOW_WORDS[word])
            else:
                numLow = 1

            ratio = ratio * (numHi / float(hi)) / (numLow / float(low))
#            if word in HIGH_WORDS:
##                Phi = Phi * float(HIGH_WORDS[word]) / float(hi)
##            else:
##                Phi = Phi * (1 / float(hi))
#
#            if word in LOW_WORDS:
##                Plow = Plow * float(LOW_WORDS[word]) / float(low)
##            else:
##                Plow = Plow * (1 / float(low))

    print ratio
    if ratio > 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Compute out of sample error on test set.
def getError():
    t = open(TEST_DATA, 'r')
    numUsers = 0.0
    total = 0.0
    for line in t:
        user = line.split(" ")[1]
        rating = int(line.split(" ")[0])
        prediction = classify(user)
        numUsers += 1.0
        if rating != prediction:
            total += 1.0
        print str(rating) + " " + str(prediction) + " " + user

    return total / numUsers



print getError()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Naive Bayes classifier for OkCupid data.  The features are the words in
# the profile and the classes are HIGH and LOW.  This is used to
# predict the rating I would give a profile.

# TODO: tweak the classifier so it works better.

from subprocess import call
from math import sqrt

# File containing training data in the form "<rating> <username>"
TRAINING_DATA = "train.dta"

# File containing test set in the form "<rating> <username>"
TEST_DATA = "test.dta"

# Dictionary
dictionary = "TWL06.txt"
```

Why is this not in ALL_CAPS like the others?

```
# Hash table containing words in highly-ranked profiles.
HIGH_WORDS = {}

# Hash table containing words in low-ranked profiles.
LOW_WORDS = {}
```

These aren't constants, so they shouldn't be global or in ALL_CAPS

```
# Number of users in each category
hi = 0
low = 0
```

Once you actually start logic, its best to do it inside a function except for really simply scripts.

```
# Add training data to the hash tables.
t = open(TRAINING_DATA, 'r')
```

Don't use single letter variable names, it results in difficult to follow code. Also, you should open a file using the with statement, to make sure it closes in all circumstances.

```
for user in t:
    rating = int(user.split(" ")[0])
    name = user.split(" ")[1]
```

Why are you passing the " " to slit instead of trusting the default. This approach is a little wasteful because you split the input twice.

```
    # Count users
    if rating == 1:
        hi += 1
    else:
        low += 1

    # Get data for each user
    call(["curl", "-o", "tmp.dta", "http://www.okcupid.com/profile/" + name])
```

Use `urllib.urlopen` to fetch urls. That you can avoid the temporary file.

```
    d = open("tmp.dta", 'r')

    # Get word list from user
    words = {}
    for line in d:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if "/" in word or "=" in word or "<" in word or ">" in word or "()" in word or "&" in word or len(word) > 10:
```

Make a list of blocked characters rather then duplicating your logic so much here. And I suspect that "()" in word wasn't what you wanted.

```
                continue
```

I try to almost always avoid continue. I suggest rewriting the logic so the following line in the if block.

```
            words[word.rstrip().lower()] = None
```

You seem to be using words as a set. Use a set.

```
    d.close()

    # Add words in this word list to our master word lists
    for word in words:
        if rating == 1:
            if word in HIGH_WORDS:
                HIGH_WORDS[word] += 1
            else:
                HIGH_WORDS[word] = 1
```

Look at `collections.Counter` to simplify this.

```
        else:
            if word in LOW_WORDS:
                LOW_WORDS[word] += 1
            else:
                LOW_WORDS[word] = 1
t.close()

print HIGH_WORDS
print LOW_WORDS

# Classify a point, assuming training has already happened.
# P(C | F1 ... Fn) proportionate to P(C) * P(F1 | C) * ... * P(Fn | C)
def classify(username):
    # P(C)
    Phi = float(hi) / float(hi + low)
    Plow = float(low) / float(hi + low)
```

Add `from __future__ import division` so that all division produce floats. Then you don't have to cast to float. I also suggest calling the variable: `probaility_high` for greater clarity.

```
    ratio = Phi / Plow
    # Get data
    call(["curl", "-o", "tmp.dta", "http://www.okcupid.com/profile/" + username])
    d = open("tmp.dta", 'r')
    for line in d:
        for word in line.split(" "):
```

There is some duplication here. You should be able to write a function that returns the words from the url.

```
            # Calculate the probability of the feature given a class
            if word in HIGH_WORDS:
                numHi = float(HIGH_WORDS[word])
            else:
                numHi = 1
            if word in LOW_WORDS:
                numLow = float(LOW_WORDS[word])
            else:
                numLow = 1

            ratio = ratio * (numHi / float(hi)) / (numLow / float(low))
#            if word in HIGH_WORDS:
##                Phi = Phi * float(HIGH_WORDS[word]) / float(hi)
##            else:
##                Phi = Phi * (1 / float(hi))
#
#            if word in LOW_WORDS:
##                Plow = Plow * float(LOW_WORDS[word]) / float(low)
##            else:
##                Plow = Plow * (1 / float(low))
```

Don't leave dead code. Delete it.

```
    print ratio
    if ratio > 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Compute out of sample error on test set.
def getError():
    t = open(TEST_DATA, 'r')
    numUsers = 0.0
    total = 0.0
    for line in t:
        user = line.split(" ")[1]
        rating = int(line.split(" ")[0])
        prediction = classify(user)
        numUsers += 1.0
        if rating != prediction:
            total += 1.0
```

Total seems a confusing name, because its only the mismatches.

```
        print str(rating) + " " + str(prediction) + " " + user

    return total / numUsers



print getError()
```

You may want to look into numpy. It'll allow much more efficient operations on large amounts of data like this.

Comment: Wow you have taught me so much.  I did not know about Counter or urlopen or a lot of the other stuff.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Winston Ewert makes some excellent comments. I'd like to add a few.

---

At a high level, it's hard to get a good idea of what's going on your program. Compare these two pieces of code:

```
import sys
p = 1
for n in xrange(sys.argv[1]):
    p *= n + 1
for n in xrange(sys.argv[2]):
    p *= (n + 1)
for n in xrange(sys.argv[1] - sys.argv[2]):
    p /= (n + 1)
print p
```

Can you spot the bug? Maybe. But it's far easier in this next piece of code:

```
import sys
def factorial(n):
    product = 1
    for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
        product *= i
    return product
def n_choose_k(n, k):
    return factorial(n) * factorial(k) / factorial(n - k)
print n_choose_k(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

The main difference is that the second piece of code has well-named functions, and that concepts on the same level of abstraction are grouped, while concepts at a lower level of abstraction are hidden (in functions).

Similarly, it's a bit hard to see what's going on in `classify` because so many things are going on at once: you're downloading a file, splitting it into words, looking up some things, multiplying some things, etc.

In the end, I suspect the classifier isn't very useful because it's being dominated by (Phi/Plow)^n, where n is the number of words in the profile that aren't in the training set. Try ignoring words that are in 0 (or perhaps <= 1) of your training profiles.

---

```
rating = int(user.split(" ")[0])
name = user.split(" ")[1]
```

can be rewritten

```
rating_text, name = user.split()
rating = int(rating_text)
```

This has an advantage that it will cause an exception to be raised if the input is not in the expected format instead of ignoring lines with more than two fields.

---

If you find yourself counting with a float (e.g. `f = 0.0; for w in ws: f += 1.0`), you're doing something wrong. Count with an integer, and convert to float later if necessary.